SQLAlchemy table with every row pointing to a single CSV file (postgres)
Basically I am trying to create a database where it stores the WeatherData for a year for a specific location, and so the first table would be 3 columns : Country, State, City all primary keys and that row in the table (say America, New York, New York City) would point to another table containing the data from the CSV or to a CSV file directly.
So far I've managed to take the data, store it to a CSV file and copy from the csv file to a table in the postgres DB:

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class WeatherData(Base):
    __tablename__= "weatherdata"
    dat: Mapped[Time] = mapped_column(TIMESTAMP, primary_key=True)
    data: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float)

base_creator = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost:5432/WeatherMan")
Base.metadata.create_all(base_creator)

results_dc.to_csv('myfile.csv')

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost:5432/WeatherMan").raw_connection()
    cursor = engine.cursor()
    cmd = """COPY weatherdata FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',', HEADER true)"""
    cursor.copy_expert(cmd,f)
    engine.commit()

Now I'm just wondering how to establish the relationship between that newly created whole table and the single row "America, New York, New York City"

I mean I can't find anything anywhere with respect to that specific problem, all the relationships I find link a row to a row or a row to many rows but it seems rather inefficient to make a one to many relationship and link every Hour of data in the WeatherData table to that user, is that the only way to do it? Can relationships be not set between a row and a full table?

I have never heard of that type of relationship.   This sort of sounds like a data warehousing problem though.  Maybe you should put all the raw data in more crude tables and then condense it into another set of tables in the same db or another db that is more normalized.  Maybe for warehouse tables: weather_2010, ..., weather 20** with city_id, dat, data.  Then the condensed tables: daily_average with city_id, average_data, date.
